# Sublime Text open all files containing search term

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sublimetext

When I pres ctrl+shift+F to search across all the files in the current scope, I get a new window listing all the files that contain that search term.

How can I quickly open all of these files?

Comment: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/BetterFindBuffer

Comment: You can double click on a file in that file listing to open each file in a row. However this doesn't open all files at once.

Comment: BetterFindBuffer is horrible. Why would it change my theme???

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Hold down the F4 key from the Search Results screen, and it will "Navigate to next match" - which causes it to open each file listed in the results.

<sub>Just a small note, if you are getting 10+ matches per file this method starts to fail because it gets slow.</sub>

Comment: This answer is perfect.

Comment: Does not work - at least when you follow what you wrote.

Comment: Jeffz, did you try on windows or mac? I've only tested on Mac.

Comment: Worked in windows. Sublime Text 2-

Comment: This is great, I thought I had a bug in this but apparently when you have a direct path and all open folders it displays two of the same file. In my case, 4 files showed up in the find window but there were only 2. Just in case someone has a similar issue. Working in ST3. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Sublime doesn't have the ability to do this out of the box; however the plugin API gives you the power to create a plugin to do something like this fairly simply (depending on how you ultimately want it to work).

I assume there are plugins available for something like this, but for reference purposes here is a simple example:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class OpenAllFoundFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit, new_window=False):
        # Collect all found filenames
        positions = self.view.find_by_selector ("entity.name.filename.find-in-files")
        if len(positions) > 0:
            # Set up the window to open the files in
            if new_window:
                sublime.run_command ("new_window")
                window = sublime.active_window ()
            else:
                window = self.view.window ()

            # Open each file in the new window
            for position in positions:
                window.run_command ('open_file', {'file': self.view.substr (position)})
        else:
            self.view.window ().status_message ("No find results")
```

This provides a command named `open_all_found_files` which could be bound to a key, added to a menu, added to the command palette, etc.

Using the notion that sublime has a custom syntax for the find results with a scope dedicated to the matching filenames, this collects all such regions and then opens the associated files.

The optional command argument `new_window` can be passed and set to `true` to open the files in a new window; leaving it off or setting it to `false` opens the files in the same window as the find results. You can of course change the default as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking I would dive into plugin development to get a solution. I love the example! Thanks.

Comment: I put this is a .py file in the user directory?

Comment: Yep; any file name is OK as long as it's a .py file. Then you just need to bind a key to the command `open_all_found_files`.

Comment: I followed those steps and hit the hotkey command when I was focused in the find file buffer window, and it did not succeed.

Comment: Hmm. I tested it out before I posted this and everything was OK. I only checked the latest version of Sublime 3 though, so possibly earlier versions (or ST2) might not. Are there are errors generated in the console?

Comment: Awesome! *thumbsup*

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that from within Sublime Text.

If you are using Linux/UNIX/OSX you can open all the files that contain a particular string or matching regex by using a combination of `grep` and `xargs` on the command line using a command like this:

```
grep -rlZ "search_str_or_regex" /path/to/search/* | xargs -0 subl

// Command line options (may vary between OSes):
//
// grep -r     Recurse directories
// grep -l     Output only the filenames of the files which contain the search pattern
// grep -Z     Output null terminated filenames
// xargs -0    Input filenames are null terminated
// xargs subl  Sublime Text executable
//
// The combination of -Z and -0 allows filenames containing spaces to be handled
```

The files will be opened in the most recently used Sublime Text window. Add `-n or --new-window` after `subl` to have them opened in a new window.

If you are using Windows, consider using [GOW](https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow/wiki) or [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the Code of OdatNurd. I had problems with the ":" and the " " at the end of the Filename... Under Mac OS Big Sur...

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

class OpenAllFoundFilesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    """
    Collect the names of all files from a Find in Files result and open them
    all at once, optionally in a new window.
    """
    def run(self, edit, new_window=False):
        # Collect all found filenames
        positions = self.view.find_by_selector("entity.name.filename.find-in-files")
        if len(positions) > 0:
            # Set up the window to open the files in
            if new_window:
                sublime.run_command("new_window")
                window = sublime.active_window()
            else:
                window = self.view.window()

            # Open each file in the new window
            for position in positions:
                file = self.view.substr (position)
                #print(file)
                file = file.replace(":","")
                window.run_command('open_file', {'file': file.strip()})
        else:
            self.view.window().status_message("No find results")

    def is_enabled(self):
        return self.view.match_selector(0, "text.find-in-files")
```